# Mysql query, select, group & sum by minutes

Tags: mysql, sum, group-by

I have a database table like so:

```
id | donation_type | donation_amount | time_inserted
1    em1              20                2012-12-07 10:01:00
2    em1              50                2012-12-07 10:01:00
3    em1              100               2012-12-07 10:01:00
4    em1              150               2012-12-07 10:02:00
5    em1              100               2012-12-07 10:02:00
6    em1              30                2012-12-07 10:02:00
7    em1              40                2012-12-07 10:03:00
8    em1              65                2012-12-07 11:16:00
```

I would like a query to count how many donations where made in each minute.
I would also like to sum the donation amount made in that minute.

So the result I would like to be returned (using the above table would be):

```
10:00:01 => 3, amount => 170 # 3 donations in 10:01:00, totaling £170
10:00:02 => 3, amount => 280 # 3 donations in 10:02:00, totaling £280
10:00:03 => 1, amount => 40 # 1 donation in 10:03:00, totaling £40
11:16:00 => 1, amount => 65 # 1 donation in 11:16:00, totaling £40
```

**EDIT**  - Example I would like returned by the SQL query

```
# Example of what I would like returned..

time                  |  donation_count  | donation_sum_in_minute
2012-12-07 10:01:00           3                  170
2012-12-07 10:02:00           3                  280
2012-12-07 10:03:00           1                  40
2012-12-07 11:16:00           1                  65  #the next hour!
```

I am using the below query to grab the total sum of donations since 10am. But I would like to also group them by minute to give me the result example above.

```
SELECT SUM(donation_amount) 
FROM `DONATION` 
WHERE `time_inserted` > '2012-12-07 10:00:00' 
AND `donation_type` = 'em1';
Returns: 807,563 # the total sum of donations since 10am today.
```

Comment: you wanna group by minute, or by year-month-day-hour-min ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with the result I would like back, Either by minute or by seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  SUM(donation_amount) AS total_donation_amount,
  EXTRACT(YEAR from time_inserted) AS year,
  EXTRACT(MONTH from time_inserted) AS month,
  EXTRACT(DAY from time_inserted) AS day,
  EXTRACT(HOUR from time_inserted) AS hour,
  EXTRACT(MINUTE from time_inserted) AS minute
FROM `DONATION`
WHERE `time_inserted` > '2012-12-07 10:00:00' 
AND `donation_type` = 'em1'
GROUP BY year, month, day, hour, minute;
```

Answer (score 5):

how about:

```
SELECT sum(donation_amount), DATE_FORMAT(time_inserted, '%Y-%m-%d %H-%i') as dates, time_inserted FROM `donation`
group by dates
order by dates asc
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(donation_type, 'Total') donation_type, 
       DATE_FORMAT(time_inserted, '%Y-%m-%d %H-%i') insertTime, 
       SUM(donation_amount), 
       COUNT(donation_type)
FROM `DONATION` 
WHERE `donation_type` = 'em1' 
GROUP BY insertTime WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    count(donation_amount) as T_Count,
    sum(donation_amount) as `Sum`
FROM
    donation
GROUP BY 
    time
```

Since each time is different so this will fetch the results OK.