# SQL to get number count per minute

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset like:

```
id       name      updated_at
1        test1     2014-06-30 09:00:00
1        test2     2014-06-30 09:01:10
1        test3     2014-06-30 09:01:23
1        test4     2014-06-30 09:01:43
1        test5     2014-06-30 09:02:02
1        test6     2014-06-30 09:02:34
1        test7     2014-06-30 09:03:22
1        test8     2014-06-30 09:03:28
```

I need to get a count of the rows by minute for the last ten minutes. So it should always return ten numbers being the count of the rows that were updated last. Any ideas on how to do it and efficiently?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13761926/2589202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Last 10 Results**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d586/22

```
--get the minute component of the update time
select minute(updated_at) as Sec
--count the number of records which have this minute
, count(1) as Cnt 
from myTable
--use group by to ensure we return 1 row per minute
group by minute(updated_at)
--list from most recent working backwards
order by minute(updated_at) desc
--return up to 10 results
limit 10
```

**Results for last 10 minutes**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d586/26

```
--get the minute component of the update time
select minute(y.d) as Min
--count the number of records which have this minute
--use m.id instead of 1 or * to ensure where there's no result from myTable
--we don't count any rows
, count(m.id) as Cnt 
from
(
    --get the current date's minute, offset by a given amount
    select date_add(now(), interval -x.a minute) d
    from
    (
       --the list of given amounts by which to offset the above date
       select 0 a
       union select 1
       union select 2
       union select 3
       union select 4
       union select 5
       union select 6
       union select 7
       union select 8
       union select 9
    ) x
) y
--left join to ensure the above list drives which results we get, 
--regardless of whether there are matching entries in myTable
left outer join myTable m
--join on the minute of each date 
on minute(m.updated_at) = minute(y.d)
--use group by to ensure we return 1 row per minute
group by minute(y.d)
--list from most recent working backwards
order by minute(y.d) desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. One more question. Your answer uses the second method, is this getting the last 10 seconds and not minutes? Also if no results are found for a certain minute I need it to return zero. So if the current datetime is 2014-06-30 09:05:28, the first two rows would return 0 for 9:05 and 9:04. So it will always return 10 numbers even if they are all zero.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)

Comment: After changing it to minute, and doing some modification this is the best answer for my needs without changing schema.

Comment: Note that grouping by minute won't work if the range of the query is ever expended over longer than an hour.

Comment: Sorry for the delay,only just seen these comments.  Should it be any use alternate versions and corrected second/minute issue now above.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want interpolated values, it quickly becomes more complicated. It's probably easiest just to create a derived table with every minute from the last ten minutes as a row, then left join to that. Here's one way to do it:

```
   select minute(now() - interval m minute) 'minutes ago', count(case when t.updated_at is not null then t.updated_at end)
from
  (select minute(now()) m
     union 
   select minute(now() - interval 1 minute) m
     union 
   select minute(now() - interval 2 minute) m
     union 
   select minute(now() - interval 3 minute) m
     union 
   select minute(now() - interval 4 minute) m
     union 
   select minute(now() - interval 5 minute) m
     union 
   select minute(now() - interval 6 minute) m
     union 
   select minute(now() - interval 7 minute) m
     union 
   select minute(now() - interval 8 minute) m
     union 
   select minute(now() - interval 9 minute) m
     union 
   select minute(now() - interval 10 minute) m
  ) q
  left join myTable t
    on q.m = minute(t.updated_at) 
      and t.updated_at >= now() - interval 10 minute
  group by m
  order by m desc
```

There's a fiddle here but you'll have to alter the schema (just add a space somewhere) and rebuild it in order to get accurate results:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3320/1