# Mysql select grouping by part of a date field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have an application log table. I currently count number of actions per minute by using the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM application_log 
WHERE activity_date LIKE '%2016-11-01 18:12%' AND activity_type = 'Full Invoice' AND status = 'Success'
```

Currently, I have to change each minute and rerun the query.

Is there any way I can get the count per minute for a period of one hour? Or go further by getting the number of actions per hour for a day?

Comment: maybe this can give you some direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638502/sql-to-get-number-count-per-minute

Comment: The answer below worked perfectly for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DATE_FORMAT` to get the time down to minutes, and group by that.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(activity_date, '%H:%i') AS time, COUNT(*)
FROM application_log
WHERE activity_date BETWEEN @start_time AND @end_time
AND activity_type = 'Full Invoice' AND status = 'Success'
GROUP BY time
ORDER BY time
```

If the time range spans more than a day, add the date to the format string.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT  concat(date(activity_date),' ',hour(activity_date),':', minute(activity_date)) as activity_date , COUNT(id) 
FROM application_log 
WHERE activity_type = 'Full Invoice' AND status = 'Success' 
group by date(activity_date),hour(activity_date), minute(activity_date);
```